# Is there a way to use an inverse pattern for stringr in R?

Tags: r, regex, datetime, stringr

I'm currently using a large data column in for time.
Time in this format is 00h00.

'\d\dh\d\d' is the regex equivalent I believe.

Though many of the cells have terms like "morning" or other terms that can't be used.

I'm trying to use the str_replace_all() function with no success.

As a follow up question, would I be able plot these times on a histogram for each occurance? That is the end goal here.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative (guess), perhaps you mean to *extract* `00h00` from each string, removing any other non-compliant portion. This might result in empty strings.

```r
vec <- c("01h23", "02h34  ", "03h45 morning", "morning")
stringr::str_extract(vec, "\\d\\d[Hh]\\d\\d")
# [1] "01h23" "02h34" "03h45" NA
```

or with base R,

```r
out <- strcapture("(\\d\\d[Hh]\\d\\d)", vec, list(tm = ""))
out
#      tm
# 1 01h23
# 2 02h34
# 3 03h45
# 4  <NA>
```

this returns a `data.frame` which can be easily extracted into a vector. If you need the non-compliant strings to be empty strings instead of `NA`, then

```r
out$tm[is.na(out$tm)] <- ""
out
#      tm
# 1 01h23
# 2 02h34
# 3 03h45
# 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to filter off non matching entries in your time column, something like this:

```r
df <- df[grepl("^\\d{2}h\\d{2}$", df$time), ]
```